# How to create a unique index with "NULLS DISTINCT" using Prisma ORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, prisma

How to create a unique index with "NULLS DISTINCT" using Prisma ORM? [Look at PG doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-unique.html#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20null%20values%20in,are%20equal%20in%20multiple%20rows.)

My first approach was to remove the `@@unique` of the model and create a custom migration, but I would lose the advantages of Prima knowing that certain columns form a unique key.

The second approach was to use `ALTER INDEX` but it's not possible to change the `NULLS DISTINCT` behavior this way.

Are there other approaches to achieve what I need without missing Prisma features? Maybe extend the `@@unique` statement...